# Find file in directory with subfolders

Tags: vb.net

I need to search a directory with sub folders for one specific file and get that file's directory path. All the examples I've found has been to search for a file type and place those files in a list.The code I have returns a count of 1, but not the file name and path. What is the best way to achieve this?

Code

```
        Dim folders As List(Of String) = New DirectoryInfo(imgLocation).EnumerateFiles(graphicName, SearchOption.AllDirectories).[Select](Function(d) d.FullName).ToList()
        For Each file In folders
            Debug.Write("file found " & file & vbCr)
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to find a specific file, you could:

```vb
Dim file As String = IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles("SearchDir",
                                                    "TheTargetFileName",
                                                    IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault
```

Then you can get it's directory:

```vb
If file IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim dir As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(file)
    '...
End If
```

Comment: This was great. If found the file and in debug mode I was able to look at the file variable and see the file.  Only problem is the directory has 56 sub-folders with graphics in it, when I ran the code it broke. I get a break mode page "The application is in break mode" the error raised is "The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. "

Comment: I threw the function into a background worker and that seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you for the help

Comment: @MHammett Most Welcome. Good luck.

Comment: @MHammett Please accept JQSOFT's answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. This is the best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get information about files you need to use FileInfo class like the example below shows:

```
 Sub SearchFiles()
    Dim files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("your directory root path here", "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each cFile In files
        Dim fi As FileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(cFile)
        Console.WriteLine("File name : " & fi.Name & " is in directory " & fi.Directory.Name & " or full path directory:  " & fi.DirectoryName)

        Next
 End Sub
```

And for a single file use this:

```
    Sub SearchSingleFile()
            Dim ext As String = ".xml"
            Dim files As List(Of String) = IO.Directory.GetFiles("put your directory here", "*" & ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(fname) fname.ToLower.EndsWith("your filename here" & ext)).ToList
            If files IsNot Nothing AndAlso files.Count > 0 Then
                Dim fInfo As IO.FileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(files(0))
                Console.WriteLine("File name : " & fInfo.Name & " is in directory " & fInfo.Directory.Name & " or full path directory:  " & fInfo.DirectoryName)
            End If
    End Sub
```

put your directory path and change extension `*.xml` in your extension

Comment: my file extension changes because it's looking for all sorts of graphic files. The directory has 56 subfolders with graphics in it, when I ran the code it broke. I get a break mode page "The application is in break mode"

Comment: This is another issue. However I think you need to uncheck this: (Take a look) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN